# Javascript PHP How to make a realtime count of table row when change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table that when i type on input field it will show those like data that i searched realtime, i mean it filtered the data when i type in textbox.

i already did the filtered but i want to add some features that shows a text that count how many rows are filtered.

like this

[image]

this is my filtering code

```
function searchTable(inputVal)
{
var table = $('#tblData');
table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
{
    var allCells = $(row).find('td');
    if(allCells.length)
    {
        var found = false;
        allCells.each(function(index, td)
        {
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
            if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
            {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: When you clicked [Add new criteria] button. You recall function searchTable and count row at here. And I think find [tr] tag is enough

Comment: Dont you know how many rows are being returned at the time you process the result from your ajax call

Comment: sir, but my add new criteria button and my search input type are different, when i type on search input field it automatically filtered, that button is for my modal display the data but i also want to display a message below how many data are display by filtering,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count all / hidden / shown childs using jQuery selectors at the end of your code.

You can use these selectors respectively; 
**tr, 
tr:hidden,
tr:visible**

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var table = $('#tblData');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found == true) $(row).show();
            else $(row).hide();
        }
    });
    /* Use these values and print / append something to your HTML. */
    var allChilds = $('#tblData').find('tr').length;
    var shownChilds = $('#tblData').find('tr:visible').length;
    var hiddenChilds = $('#tblData').find('tr:hidden').length;
    /* Use these values and print / append something to your HTML. */
    var countTemplate = "Your template, Total:"+allChilds;
    $("#counts").html(countTemplate);

}
```

Comment: sir but its duplicating when i append, how do i remove the previous append on keyup

Comment: I have updated my code. Add `<div id="counts"></div>` to your HTML and update content of it on each `searchTable()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified code of your function:

```
searchTable = function(inputVal) {
  showing = 0;
  rows.each(function(index, row) {
    var allCells = $(row).find('td');
    if (allCells.length) {
      var found = false;
      allCells.each(function(index, td) {
        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
        if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
          showing++;
          found = true;
          return false;
        }
      });
      if (found == true) $(row).show();
      else $(row).hide();
    }
    $showingSpan.text(showing.toString());
    $totalSpan.text(total.toString());
    $filteredSpan.text((total - showing).toString());
  });
};
```

And here's [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lob70s4o/) with implemented functionality of counting filtered and visible rows. You didn't mention what version of jQuery you are using so I assumed the 2.2.4 version.